# SQL error stating invalid column name when I have verification if it exists. Why?

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

There is staging script, which creates new column DOCUMENT_DEFINITION_ID stages it with values of MESSAGE_TYPE_ID + 5 and then removes column MESSAGE_TYPE_ID.

First time everything run ok, but when I run script second time I'm getting this error:

> Invalid column name 'MESSAGE_TYPE_ID'.

It makes no sense since, I have verification if that column exists.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'MESSAGE_TYPE_ID' AND TABLE_NAME = 'DOCUMENT_QUEUE')
BEGIN
  UPDATE DOCUMENT_QUEUE SET DOCUMENT_DEFINITION_ID = MESSAGE_TYPE_ID + 5 --Error here.. but condition is not met
```

Why?

Comment: This brings some light I think: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190686.aspx

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try this

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'MESSAGE_TYPE_ID' AND TABLE_NAME = 'DOCUMENT_QUEUE')
BEGIN
   EXEC( 'UPDATE DOCUMENT_QUEUE SET DOCUMENT_DEFINITION_ID = MESSAGE_TYPE_ID + 5 ')
END
```

It bypasses the delayed name resolution by wrapping the update in dynamic statement.

Comment: Ah.. dynamic SQL! This is definitely the quickest solution to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Delayed resolution of names only happens on tables that don't exist. You will need to drop and create the entire table.

Answer (score -1):

Also, you can cheat the SQL validator by appending the next code at the begging of your script:

```
IF 1 = 0
    alter table DOCUMENT_QUEUE add MESSAGE_TYPE_ID int NULL;
```

This code will never run but the SQL validator doesn't know about it. :)